# El intent no reconoce el Activity

Tags: android

**Translated:**

I have an activity in Android that asks the user data and when I give the button should call another activity and show other choices, I do it with Intent and brings me a layout with nothing when there is already a texts

Class Java code that calls the other activity:

```
package bastardapps.techmaker;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Danilo on 27/10/2016.
 */

public class menuTest extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lv;
private Button btnInicioCategoria;
public static Encuestado persona;
public EditText etNombre;
public EditText etEdad;
public EditText etCorreo;
public EditText etTelefono;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    persona = new Encuestado();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menutest);

    /*
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvdatos);

    ArrayList<Dato> listDatos = new ArrayList<>();

    listDatos.add(new Dato(1,"Tu Nombre","Nombre","text"));
    listDatos.add(new Dato(2,"Edad","Edad","number"));
    listDatos.add(new Dato(3,"Correo","Correo","textEmailAddress"));
    listDatos.add(new Dato(4, "Telefono","Telefono","phone"));

    opcionDatos od = new opcionDatos(this,listDatos);

    lv.setAdapter(od);*/

    btnInicioCategoria = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInicioMenu);
    etNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etnombre);
    etEdad = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etedad);
    etCorreo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etcorreo);
    etTelefono = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ettelefono);

    btnInicioCategoria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nombre = etNombre.getText().toString();
            String edad = etEdad.getText().toString();
            String correo = etCorreo.getText().toString();
            String telefono = etTelefono.getText().toString();

            if(nombre.isEmpty() || edad.isEmpty() || correo.isEmpty() || telefono.isEmpty())
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(menuTest.this);

                dlgAlerta.setMessage("Por favor digita todos tus datos");
                dlgAlerta.setTitle("TechMaker Alert");
                dlgAlerta.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                dlgAlerta.show();
            }else
            {
                persona.setNombre(nombre);
                persona.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(edad));
                persona.setCorreo(correo);
                persona.setTelefono(Long.parseLong(telefono));

                Intent i = new Intent(menuTest.this,categorias.class);

                startActivity(i);

            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Code named activity:

```
package bastardapps.techmaker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
  * Created by Danilo on 7/11/2016.
 */

public class categorias extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call:

> setContentView(R.layout.categorias_layout_id);

This will setup the layout of your activity. You done it right on the first activity.